# Get Return Value from one function and use on another

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to do something so seemingly basic in python, but i think im overthinking it.

Im trying to get the return value of `password` from `create_password()` and use it in `store_password()` where I put `<<HERE>>`

How can I accomplish this?

```
def create_password(self):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits
    password =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(self.pass_char) )
    return (password)

def store_password(self):
    try:
        connection = sqli.connect('pw.db')
    except:
        print("Error occurred!")

    with connection:
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('''
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_passwords(
                    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    password text
                    '''
        )
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_passwords VALUES(?)', <<HERE>>)
```

Thank you.

Comment: The first thing to notice it that you have defined your functions like class methods with an implicit first argument `self`. If they are outside a class this is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the info @KlausD. - but they *are* in the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both function are inside the same class, called in this examples *MyPasswordMaker*.

You can pass the password as a parameter:

```
def store_password(self, password):
    try:
        connection = sqli.connect('pw.db')
    except:
        print("Error occurred!")

    with connection:
       cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('''
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_passwords(
                    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    password text
                    '''
        )
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_passwords VALUES(?)', password)


myPasswordMaker = MyPasswordMaker()
password = myPasswordMaker.create_password()
myPasswordMaker.store_password(password)
```

Or you can store the password in a class variable

```
class MyPasswordMaker:
    def create_password(self):
        characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits
        self.password =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(self.pass_char) )

    def store_password(self):
        try:
            connection = sqli.connect('pw.db')
        except:
            print("Error occurred!")

        with connection:
            cur = connection.cursor()
            cur.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_passwords(
                id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                password text
                '''
            )
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_passwords VALUES(?)', self.password)
```

Or call *create_password()* inside *store_password()*:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_passwords VALUES (?)', self.create_password())
```

Comment: This is great explanation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is basically using the function that you have already built `create_password(self)` and assuming that they both belong to the same class you should be able to call `create_password(self)` within the second function `store_password(self)`

So to return the password you created you can just call `create_password(self)` in place of `<<HERE>>`.

What tabac has suggested will also work, you will need to make sure, however that the method `create_password(self)` will have to be called before so that the `self.password` variable is assigned.

Your code would become

`cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_passwords VALUES(?)', self.create_password(self))`

Answer (score 0):

I assume these methods both belong to the same class. If so you can attach the `password` to the class instance and use it in `store_password`. Use `self` for that.

```
def create_password(self):
    # code...
    self.password = password

def store_password(self):
    # Access password by doing self.password
```

Answer (score 0):

This line should work, if you have defined both funtions within a class.

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_passwords VALUES(?)', self.create_password())
```

If not, you need to remove the `self,` from both and then write

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_passwords VALUES(?)', create_password())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example might help in your situation?

```
import random
import sqli
import string


def main():
    password = create_password(20)
    store_password(password)


def create_password(length):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
    password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
    return password


def store_password(password):
    try:
        connection = sqli.connect('pw.db')
    except:
        print('Error occurred!')
    else:
        with connection:
            cur = connection.cursor()
            cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_passwords (
                           id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                           password text)''')
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_passwords VALUES (?)', password)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you provide more of your code (specifically more of the class that your methods are from and especially what calls the `create_password` method), it would be a lot easier to fix your code.